# "Add ASP.Net folder" not enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following the MVC Music Store tutorial and it says I can create the App_Data folder by clicking on Project -> Add ASP.Net folder -> App_Data.

However when I do that I see that all the standard ASP.Net folders are disabled and cannot be selected. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Make sure you are not running (Debugin ) your we app.

Comment: I came here from the same tutorial - wonder how many people google this when they get to Part 4?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I came across this problem too.  You have to make sure the project is selected in the Solution Explorer and not just some file or folder within the project.  If the project is selected, your Add ASP.NET folder options will become enabled.  Alternatively, right click on the project in the tree and go to Add -> Add ASP.NET Folder.  That will make sure the project is indeed selected.

Answer (score 9):

Check to see if the folder already exists physically (using Windows Explorer, not Visual Studio Solution Explorer).

`Visual Studio` won't allow you to add `App_Data` if there is already a folder there of the same name even if the project doesn't "`include`" it (meaning that it won't appear in the project despite being in the folders).

You can "`Add existing item`" to include it or try deleting the physical folder then adding the `ASP.NET` folder.

I don't know why the physical folder existed but wasn't included in the project.

To be certain, I added the folder as an existing item to the project, deleted from the project (which dumped that folder into the recycle bin), then added the `ASP.NET` `App_Data` folder (which created a new one).

Just to be sure.

Comment: Probably because it's usually hidden unless 'Show All Files' is selected. (Looks a bit like the copy icon in the set of buttons at the top of Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple...  Look in your solution explorer and you will find a wonderful thing called "App_Data"...it's already there!!

Cheers!!

Comment: You opened my eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

Open up your {projectname}.csproj (if you are on vb, that would be .vbproj. if so [I mean your project is on vb], ignore this answer. this is for C# projects. I'm not use if the ProjectTypeGuids are the same for vb)

you will see something like following;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{1382C465-ACF7-4550-A6FA-6305399CDA65}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>
        {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};
        {fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
    </ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WebApplication2</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WebApplication2</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

did you see `<ProjectTypeGuids>` section. make sure that you have  {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21} guid there. otherwise, you won't be able to get asp.net specific tooling features.

Comment: then, that's weird :s please put the solution here if you find. I'm wondering

Comment: try to create a new MVC 3 application from scratch and see if it is working or not. That way you will be able to see if the problem is related to VS2010 or your project.

Comment: Yes. If I create a project and the first thing I do is to create an App_Forder

Comment: so your problem is with your project.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple.

Select the project and then follow the cursor as required. What you were missing was selecting the project (not the solution).

After that then you will have create a AppData.

Comment: please add English translation